# Convert MKV to audio only in Linux

Tags: kubuntu, video, ffmpeg, convert, mkv

I am trying to convert a video (recorded with [OBS](https://obsproject.com)) from MKV to audio only (e.g. MP3 or OGG)

in k(Ubuntu).

I tried this command first :

```sh
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mkv -acodec libvorbis output.ogg
```

the result was a video again.

i was searching stackoverlow for converting MKV to audio. I found many converting answers to other video-formats but not to audio.

Operating System:

```
Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mkv -vn -c:a libvorbis output.ogg
```

`-vn` tells FFmpeg to ignore all video streams.

To transcode *all audio streams* from your input media, and also add some libvorbis options try the following:

```
ffmpeg -i myVideo.mkv -map 0:a -c:a libvorbis -b:a 96k output.ogg
```

Another sound option for libvorbis could be something like: `-c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5`.